# Why is this Lwt based and seemingly concurrent code so inconsistent

Tags: ocaml, lwt

I am trying to create concurrent examples of Lwt and came up with this little sample

```
let () =
  Lwt_main.run (
      let start = Unix.time () in
      Lwt_io.open_file Lwt_io.Input "/dev/urandom" >>= fun data_source ->
      Lwt_unix.mkdir "serial" 0o777 >>= fun () ->
      Lwt_list.iter_p
        (fun count ->
         let count = string_of_int count in
         Lwt_io.open_file
           ~flags:[Unix.O_RDWR; Unix.O_CREAT]
           ~perm:0o777
           ~mode:Lwt_io.Output ("serial/file"^ count ^ ".txt") >>= fun h ->
         Lwt_io.read ~count:52428800
                     data_source >>= Lwt_io.write_line h)
        [0;1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9] >>= fun () ->
      let finished = Unix.time () in
      Lwt_io.printlf "Execution time took %f seconds" (finished -. start))
```

EDIT: With asking for 50GB it was:
      "However this is incredibly slow and basically useless. 
      Does the inner bind need to be forced somehow?"

EDIT: I originally had written asking for 50 GB and it never finished, now I have a different problem with asking for 50MB, The execution is nearly instantaneously and du -sh reports only a directory size of 80k.

EDIT: I have also tried the code with explicitly closing the file handles with the same bad result.

I am on `OS X` latest version and compile with

`ocamlfind ocamlopt -package lwt.unix main.ml -linkpkg -o Test`

(I have also tried `/dev/random`, yes I'm using wall-clock time.)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

So, your code has some issues.

### Issue 1

The main issue is that you understood the `Lwt_io.read` function incorrectly (and nobody can blame you!).

```
val read : ?count : int -> input_channel -> string Lwt.t
  (** [read ?count ic] reads at most [len] characters from [ic]. It
      returns [""] if the end of input is reached. If [count] is not
      specified, it reads all bytes until the end of input. *)
```

When `~count:len` is specified it will read **at most** `len` characters. At most, means, that it can read less. But if the `count` option is omitted, then it will read all data. I, personally, find this behavior unintuitive, if not weird. So, this *at most* means up to `len` or less, i.e., no guarantee is provided that it will read exactly `len` bytes. And indeed, if you add a check into your program:

```
 Lwt_io.read ~count:52428800 data_source >>= fun data ->
 Lwt_io.printlf "Read %d bytes" (String.length data) >>= fun () ->
 Lwt_io.write h data >>= fun () ->
```

You will see, that it will read only `4096` bytes, per try:

```
Read 4096 bytes
Read 4096 bytes
Read 4096 bytes
Read 4096 bytes
Read 4096 bytes
Read 4096 bytes
Read 4096 bytes
Read 4096 bytes
Read 4096 bytes
Read 4096 bytes
```

Why `4096`? Because this is the default buffer size. But it actually doesn't matter.

### Issue 2

`Lwt_io` module implements a buffered IO. That means that all your writes and reads are not going directly to a file, but are buffered in the memory. That means, that you should remember to `flush` and `close`. Your code doesn't close descriptors on finish, so you can end up with a situation when some buffers are left unflushed after a program is terminated. `Lwt_io` in particular, flushes all buffers before program exit. But you shouldn't rely on this undocumented feature (it may hit you in future, when you will try any other buffered io, like fstreams from standard C library). So, always close your files (another problem is that today file descriptors are the most precious resource, and their leaking is very hard to find).

### Issue 3

Don't use `/dev/urandom` or `/dev/random` to measure io. For the former you will measure the performance of random number generator, for the latter you will measure the flow of entropy in your machine. Both are quite slow. Depending on the speed of your CPU, you will rarely get more than 16 Mb/s, and it is much less, then `Lwt` can throughput. Reading from `/dev/zero` and writing to `/dev/null` will actually perform all transfers in memory and will show the actual speed, that can be achieved by your program. A well-written program will be still bounded by the kernel speed. In the example program, provided below, this will show an average speed of 700 MB/s.

### Issue 4

Don't use the buffered io, if you're really striving for a performance. You will never get the maximum. For example, `Lwt_io.read` will read first at buffer, then it will create a `string` and copy data to that string. If you really need some performance, then you should provide your own buffering. In most cases, there is no need for this, as `Lwt_io` is quite performant. But if you need to process dozens of megabytes per second, or need some special buffering policy (something non-linear), you may need to think about providing your own buffering. The good news is that `Lwt_io` allows you to do this. You can take a look at an [example](https://gist.github.com/ivg/650e6862b263c8e8728a) program, that will measure the performance of `Lwt` input/output. It mimics a well-known `pv` program.

### Issue 5

You're expecting to get some performance by running threads in parallel. The problem is that in your test there is no place for the concurrency. `/dev/random` (as well as `/dev/zero`) is one device that is bounded only by CPU. This is the same, as just calling a `random` function. It will always be `available`, so no system call will block on it. Writing to a regular file is also not a good place for concurrency. First of all, usually there is only one hard-drive, with one writing head in it. Even if system call will block and yield control to another thread, this will result in a performance digression, as two threads will now compete for the header position. If you have SSD, there will not be any competition for the header, but the performance will be still worse, as you will spoil your caches. But fortunately, usually writing on regular files doesn't block. So your threads will run consequently, i.e., they will be serialized.

Comment: There is so much here that it would have taken me a long time to figure it out on my own, thank you very much. Is there any seemingly real world example that shows off concurrency in lwt?

Comment: I would suggest to read Chapter 18 of [RWO ](https://realworldocaml.org/v1/en/html/concurrent-programming-with-async.html). Although, it is about `Async` library, they are very close, so it is quite easy to reimplement it in `Lwt`.

Comment: I should have said not including web requests related stuff (I"m aware that lwt is used in ocsigen). I was meaning something more algorithmic, like a map reduce kind of thing, or some kind of distributed algorithm. I found this http://www.amazon.com/Concurrent-Programming-Algorithms-Principles-Foundations/dp/3642320260, but I'm really looking for actual code...

Comment: Well, lwt is more about concurrency, rather then distributed programming. For the latter there're `mpi`, `zmq`, etc. But you still can have real parallelism, for `async` and `lwt` using [async_parallel][1] and [lwt-parallel][2] libraries
[1]: https://opam.ocaml.org/packages/async_parallel/async_parallel.112.17.00/
[2]: https://opam.ocaml.org/packages/lwt-parallel/lwt-parallel.0.1.0/

Answer (score 3):

If you look at your files, you'll see they're each 4097K – that's 4096K that was read from /dev/urandom, plus one byte for the newline. You're reaching a buffer maximum with Lwt_io.read, so even though you say ~count:awholelot, it only gives you ~count:4096.

I don't know what the canonical Lwt way to do this is, but here's one alternative:

```
open Lwt

let stream_a_little source n = 
    let left = ref n in
    Lwt_stream.from (fun () -> 
        if !left <= 0 then return None
        else Lwt_io.read ~count:!left source >>= (fun s -> 
            left:=!left - (Bytes.length s);
            return (Some s)
        ))

let main () =
    Lwt_io.open_file ~buffer_size:(4096*8) ~mode:Lwt_io.Input "/dev/urandom" >>= fun data_source ->
        Lwt_unix.mkdir "serial" 0o777 >>= fun () ->
            Lwt_list.iter_p
        (fun count ->
            let count = string_of_int count in
            Lwt_io.open_file
           ~flags:[Unix.O_RDWR; Unix.O_CREAT]
           ~perm:0o777
           ~mode:Lwt_io.Output ("serial/file"^ count ^ ".txt") >>= (fun h ->
               Lwt_stream.iter_s (Lwt_io.write h)
               (stream_a_little data_source 52428800)))
        [0;1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9]

let timeit f =
        let start = Unix.time () in
        f () >>= fun () ->
            let finished = Unix.time () in
            Lwt_io.printlf "Execution time took %f seconds" (finished -. start)

let () =
    Lwt_main.run (timeit main)
```

EDIT: Note that lwt is a *cooperative* threading library; when you have two threads going "at the same time", they don't actually do stuff in your OCaml process at the same time. OCaml is (as of yet) single-core, so when one thread is moving, the others wait nicely until that thread says "OK, I've done some work, you others go". So when you try to stream to 8 files at the same time, you're basically doling out a little randomness to file1, then a little to file2, … a little to file8, then (if there's still work left to do) a little to file1, then a little to file2 etc. This makes sense if you're waiting on lots of input anyway (say your input is coming over the network), and your main process has a lot of time to go through each thread and check "is there any input?", but when all your threads are just reading from /dev/random, it'd be much faster to just fill up one file first, then the second, etc. And assuming it's possible for several CPU's to read /dev/(u)random in parallell (and your drive can keep up), it'd of course be much faster to load ncpu reads at the same time, but then you need multicore (or just do this in shell script).

EDIT2: showed how to increase buffer size on the reader, ups the speed a bit ;) Note that you can also simply set the buffer_size as high as you want on your old example, which will read it all in one go, but you can't get more than your buffer_size unless you read several times.

Comment: This seemingly works, but 1) How did you know about PIPEBUFFER? Its not mentioned AT ALL on https://ocsigen.org/lwt/2.4.8/api/Lwt_io, 2) Why is it still so slow?

Comment: 1) I ran your example and saw that the files were just over 4096K – and I've been bitten by that buffer before. Though you might want to report a documentation issue at https://github.com/ocsigen/lwt/issues/new

Comment: 2) If you want it to read/write a whole lot of data quickly to/from disk, I don't think you should be using Lwt (the simple functions from Unix would probably be fastest). If you do use Lwt for this, it might be quicker if you read more data at a time and then write.

Comment: Its ridiculous....grepping thorugh the source code doesn't give a single hit on pipebuffer. So you're saying that the library for concurrent code that specializes in blocking code is slow and its best not to use it for this. This is enough to make me give up completely on lwt.

Comment: Actually, I looked at https://github.com/ocsigen/lwt/blob/master/src/unix/lwt_io.ml now and they define the buffer size 4096 there, so it's not the Unix-defined buffer, but their own default setting. Changing this in the example makes it a lot faster (as I said, "quicker if you read more data at a time"). But I agree it still warrants documentation, I haven't found any of these "read some, write some, avoid buffer trouble" examples in the manual at all.

Comment: Though I don't agree with dismissing the library based on performance here – as I wrote above, this is a kind of job where (if you're using ocaml at all) you'll do it much quicker sequentially. Where lwt shines is where your program actually has to wait on IO.

Comment: your answer is incorrect. There is no issue with `Lwt` the OP code has some issues. The only issue is that `count` option is not documented very clearly and, to my opinion, adding this option was just a bad design decision.

Comment: You should probably set the buffer size for the output as well, and there is also `Lwt_io.set_default_buffer_size` that changes the default size (I usually set it to 64k or 128k).

Comment: (I don't think I claimed there was anything wrong with `Lwt` apart from documentation.)